# WAVE file format

Tags: audio, android, pcm

im making an android application that generates a signal and save it as a wave file. i looked everywhere and i found that i should "write" the file's structure  "manually" like in [here](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/), because Android doesnt support wave formats.

the file is generated but its not "playable", even on Matlab i get this message: `Incorrect chunk size information in WAV file.`

here's the code, please tell me if anything wrong with the structure.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {  

int duration=1;
int sampleRate=48000;
int numSample=duration*sampleRate;
double sample[]=new double[numSample];
double freq1=23000;
double freq2=24000;
byte[] generatedSnd= new byte[2*numSample];
Handler handler=new Handler();
long mySubChunk1Size = 16;
short myBitsPerSample= 16;
int myFormat = 1;
int myChannels = 1;
long myByteRate = sampleRate * myChannels * myBitsPerSample/8;
int myBlockAlign = (int) (myChannels * myBitsPerSample/8);
long myChunk2Size = generatedSnd.length* myChannels * myBitsPerSample/8;
long myChunkSize = 36 + myChunk2Size;


@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Thread thread=new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            try {
                genTone();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block                                                                                                                                                                                          

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    handler.post(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            playSound();
        }
    });
}
    });
    thread.start();

}    

protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

}
void genTone() throws IOException{


    double instfreq=0, numerator;

    for (int i=0;i<numSample; i++ )
    {
        numerator=(double)(i)/(double)numSample;
         instfreq   =freq1+(numerator*(freq2-freq1));
         if ((i % 1000) == 0) {
                Log.e("Current Freq:", String.format("Freq is:  %f at loop %d of %d", instfreq, i, numSample));
            }
        sample[i]=Math.sin(2*Math.PI*i/(sampleRate/instfreq));

    }
     int idx = 0;
        for (final double dVal : sample) {
            // scale to maximum amplitude
            final short val = (short) ((dVal * 32767)); // max positive sample for signed 16 bit integers is 32767
            // in 16 bit wave PCM, first byte is the low order byte (pcm: pulse control modulation)
            generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) (val & 0x00ff);
            generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) ((val & 0xff00) >>> 8);


        }
       DataOutputStream dd=new DataOutputStream( new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/tessst.wav" ));    
      dd.writeBytes("RIFF");
      dd.writeInt(0); // Final file size not known yet, write 0 
      dd.writeBytes("WAVE");
      dd.writeBytes("fmt ");
      dd.writeInt(Integer.reverseBytes(16)); // Sub-chunk size, 16 for PCM
      dd.writeShort(Short.reverseBytes((short) 1)); // AudioFormat, 1 for PCM
      dd.writeShort(Short.reverseBytes( (short) myChannels));// Number of channels, 1 for mono, 2 for stereo
      dd.writeInt(Integer.reverseBytes(sampleRate)); // Sample rate
      dd.writeInt(Integer.reverseBytes( (sampleRate*myBitsPerSample*myChannels/8))); // Byte rate, SampleRate*NumberOfChannels*BitsPerSample/8
      dd.writeShort(Short.reverseBytes((short) (myChannels*myBitsPerSample/8))); // Block align, NumberOfChannels*BitsPerSample/8
      dd.writeShort(Short.reverseBytes( myBitsPerSample)); // Bits per sample
      dd.writeBytes("data");
      dd.write(generatedSnd,0,numSample);
      dd.close();


    }
```

Comment: This is not a sound design or production related question.  This is a question about low level file formats.  It is best asked on StackOverflow and is not on topic here.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't written the size of the 'data' chunk just before the audio data (generatedSnd). You also need to go back and write the size of the 'RIFF' chunk before closing the stream. In this example code you could pre calculate this and not write the zero in the first place.